Do we say "to go up to somebody" to mean "to move towards somebody, in order to talk to them"?
We only have the "come up (to somebody)" in dictionaries, we don't see its counterpart "go up (to somebody)".

come up (to somebody) ​to move towards somebody, in order to talk to them
He came up to me and asked me the way to the station.

Do we need to worry about the direction when using come up (to somebody)?
There are 2 paragraphs:
1- "Tom went to a bar. He saw a nice girl and he came up to her and invited her to dance with him"
2- "Tom was sitting in a bar. A nice girl saw him and she came up to him and invited him to dance with her"
I also learned the difference between "go" and "come".
The Paragraph 1 should be "Tom went to a bar. He saw a nice girl and he went up to her and invited her to dance with him".
But I am not sure if "go up to somebody" means "to move towards somebody, in order to talk to them". I can not find it in proper well-known dictionaries such as Oxford or Cambridge.
Of course, if we use "walk up to somebody", we don't worry about "go" or "come".
Do we say "to go up to somebody" to mean "to move towards somebody, in order to talk to them"?

Why do you think this? But "go up to somebody" does not mean "to move towards somebody, in order to talk to them"

@MichaelHarvey, do you have any dictionary entries that say "go up to somebody"

It's in McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs: "to approach someone or something. The temperature will go up to near one hundred today. I went up to her and asked her for a match." Merriam-Webster lists up as an adverb with meaning "so as to arrive or approach", so you can argue whether it's a phrasal verb or just a verb with an adverb (certainly you can "walk up" and many other similar expressions).

Although @StuartF has linked to what seem to be American sources, those definitions are correct for British English too.


I also learned the difference between "go" and "come".

This is the key. You didn't elaborate, but hopefully you learned that the difference is about where the speaker is. The difference between "go home" and "come home" is that I tell you to "come home" when I'm already home, and I tell you to "go home" when I'm not.
So if you and I are together at a bar and see a girl at a distance, I might tell you to "go to her," because you'd be going to a place that I'm currently not. For some reason, "go up to her" is not very idiomatic in this situation; I'd be more likely to say "go over to her." But in retelling the story, it would be idiomatic to say "... and then Tom went up to her," and I could imagine other idiomatic present tense things, like "Dude, if you can't even go up to her, what's the point?"
But if I'm already chatting with the girl and want to tell you to join us, I use "come." (Again, probably "come over to us" rather than "come up to us" for an imperative, but "come up to" is more idiomatic in a declarative, like when retelling the story ("... so then Tom came up to her, and...").

Short answer: Yes. To go up to [someone] means to approach them. In most cases, it means the same as to go over to them, although there can be slightly different inferences. We tend to say someone "came over" if they were in already in the vicinity - an example might be a work colleague in the same office approaching you. Saying someone "came up" to you can imply it was unexpected, for example, if a stranger came up to you in the street.
Why some prepositions become idiomatic in certain contexts is often just down to usage over time. There can be reasons for a particular choice - the directions "up" and "down" are loosely associated with the compass directions north and south, so someone might say "come up and see me" if they live north, but "come down and see me" if they live south. However, sometimes a particular choice becomes popular - for example, the line "come up and see me sometime" became something of a popular saying after actress Mae West spoke/sang it in the movie She Done Him Wrong. In the literal context of the movie she may have said "come up" because  she had a private room upstairs, so she was literally higher up, but out of context it sounds seductive, as if the person is putting themselves in an elevated position and inviting someone into that empowered position.
